# Get-TfsServer -Credential not working

Tags: powershell, tfs

I have an xml file that I store a single `PSCredential` object in an xml file that I get by

`Get-Credential | Export-CliXml c:\creds.xml`

`$credentials = Import-CliXml c:\creds.xml`

I then try to call `Get-TfsWorkspace` with

`$tfss = Get-TfsWorkspace -Server $tfs_server -Credential $credentials`

I keep getting the `TF30063` unauthorized error when trying to use my `PSCredential` object i store in the xml, however, if I leave out the `-Credential` flag I am presented with a dialog that requests my credentials, and I can successfully login to tfs that way, however, that defeats the purpose of my automation.

Is there something I am missing when passing a `PSCredential` object as the `-Credential`?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried it with `invoke-command -computer $computer -scriptblock {whoami} -Credential $credentials`, don't seem to have problem and returned the user I passed from the credential file. I guess this is not a credential problem.

Comment: Yea, I'm just not sure why when the dialog accepts my credentials it's fine, but when i build a credentials object and pass that, it doesnt.

Comment: I deleted the existing windows credentials in my credential manager, and it seems to work now.  However, when I call Update-TfsWorkspace i still get prompted for credentials